# В Python 3.9 отсутствует метод проверки жив ли поток .isAlive(). Есть ли другие альтернативные методы проверить жив ли поток?

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

В Python 3.9 отсутствует метод проверки жив ли поток .isAlive(). Есть ли другие альтернативные методы проверить жив ли поток, чтобы его перезапустить при необходимости? Так как мой поток периодически засыпает каждые 5 минут и должен просыпаться через каждые 5 минут time.sleep(300), но раз в сутки поток умирает не понятно почему, и я хочу отследить и поймать момент, а метод .isAlive() начиная с питона 3.9 больше не существует.

Comment: Используйте [is_alive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive)